# unable to connect ios 9.1 device to xcode 7.1

Tags: objective-c, ios9.1, xcode7.1

I am trying to run application in a device with iOS 9.1 from xcode 7.1. xcode is keep crashing. I am unable to install the application in any ios 9.1 devices. I have tried 3 different devices and getting the same problem. My code is in objective-c.

Comment: same issue here, Xcode 7.1 to ios9.1, was told device unavailable, anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have uninstalled the xcode and then installed xcode 7.2 again. It solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something for fix it, maybe it's just some stupid errors from xcode.

1. Try to clean then build again.
2. Add a devices for development then test again.
3. Report to Apple.

   - Check your iOS Target Deployment first.

Answer (score 0):

Also try following steps

1. Also try reinstalling Xcode 7 and while installing close Xcode.
2. Check in Xcode Preferences whether Simulator for iOS9 is installed or not.
3. also check whether your itunes open when plugin device.